# How do I get the "Finish Bonus" and how much is it actually worth?

Tags: persona-q

At the end of a battle sometimes I get a "Finish Bonus" on the win screen. It looks like an experience boost. Do I get this from winning on an All-Out Attack or just by winning in one turn? And what is the actual bonus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a finish bonus if your battle is ended during the All-Out Attack.

Comment: Do you know what the amount of the bonus is?